# Make a UIView change its superview (or superview's superview)?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have four `UIView`s: `viewA` is the root view, vhich has `viewB` as its subview. `viewB` has `viewC` as its subview and `viewC` has `viewD` as its subview. So there is a hierarchy of four views. `viewD` is basically a button that can be tapped to do something. Because the operation has to do with database, it may takes a while. So I want a dark opaque `UIView` with a `UIActivityIndicator` at the center to tell the user to wait for a moment and prevent other tapping action that may cause trouble. However, the dark view has to be put in `viewA` to make it cover all the screen. Here are what I tried (and succeeded) but I want to know whether there are any easier ways to do it.

1. Access `viewA` from `viewD` by `viewD.superview.superview.superview`. However it's not very flexible because once the hierarchy is changed, this chain is likely to be changed.
2. Use delegation. `viewD.delegate = viewA`. However, `viewD` is created by `viewC` (its direct superview) which is created by `viewB`, which is created by `viewA`. So if `viewD`, `viewC`, and `viewB` are not `@property` of its respective superclass (accessing by `viewA.viewB.viewC.viewD` is not possible), then `viewA` cannot have a pointer to `viewD`, which will make the delegation impossible (as far as I understand).
3. Use `NSNotification`. Make `viewD` post a `@"ActivityIndicatorShouldBePutOn"` notification and make `viewA` an observer of it. However, `NSNotification` is used for broadcasting right? So it is somewhat inappropriate.
4. As long as this case goes (the dark mask is put on the whole screen), I can use something related to `UIApplication` to access the screen and put it direct onto it. But if I want to put it only on a part of a screen for a different purpose, then this is not going to work.

So I want to ask whether there is a better way of doing it or whether one method mentioned above is the standard way.

Comment: Don't you have a view controller in the game?

Comment: @HermannKlecker Yes I have one but because `viewD` is created by `viewC`, not the view controller, then how can the view controller make any difference?

Comment: I just got a guts feeling that you should use a view controller to create your views. That should be the standard way for which you asked. If you don't want that then you should use option 3 or add the new activity indicator thingy directly to the window. (Afaik the window itself does not rotate to portrait or upside-down.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use option 3 even though its a broadcast, you can listen to it with only 1 observer. then just have different notifications for each UIView

I would say that is the easiest/guaranteed fix even though it may not be elegant, nothing wrong with it imo.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the activity indicator view to the main window. You can get the keyWindow using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend this API [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD). It has a good look and feel and is dead easy to use:

[image]

Displaying the activityIndicator

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
```

Removing it

```
[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
```